# Sumar valores de una columna de un datatable usando linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

Con la siguiente tabla:

```
| Animales | cantidad |
-----------------------
| Perros   | 5        |
| Gatos    | 3        |
| Loros    | 2        |
```

Creo el datatable:

```
   Dim tabla As New DataTable()
        tabla.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(1) {New DataColumn("Animales", GetType(String)),
                                               New DataColumn("cantidad", GetType(Integer))})
        tabla.Rows.Add("Perros", 5)
        tabla.Rows.Add("Gatos", 3)
        tabla.Rows.Add("Loros", 2)
```

Quiero obtener la suma del total de animales: 10

Usando MySQL sería algo así

```
SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM tabla
```

Mis intentos en linq rondan esta fórmula pero sin éxito:

```
Dim qry = From a in tabla
          Let Animal = a(0)
          Let Cantidad = a(1)
          Select sum(cantidad)
```

Aún me siento muy patoso con linq así que agradecería cualquier ayuda. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unas cuantas opciones dependiendo de la sintaxis que prefieres:

```
Dim total = (From a In tabla.AsEnumerable()
             Select a.Field(Of Integer)("cantidad")).Sum()
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/SAQNGP47477)</kbd>

o...

```
Dim total = tabla.AsEnumerable().Sum(Function(t) t.Field(Of Integer)("cantidad"))
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/VXC34588)</kbd>

Puedes encontrar más información sobre las peculiaridades de usar LINQ con un `DataTable` aquí: [LINQ query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11593/4955425).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero a la hora de trabajarlo con el DataTable  me da problemas. Voy a editar la pregunta para reproducir exactamente lo que yo tengo.

Comment: Ah, disculpa. aunque ya habías mencionado que era un datatable en el título, se me metió en la cabeza que era otra cosa. Hicistes muy bien en modificar la pregunta para que sea un [mcve]. Modifiqué la respuesta para que funcione con tu ejemplo.